# PHP kerberos delegation

Tags: php, curl, kerberos

How could I forward kerberos auth to another server (using CURL) with php.
I have `$_SERVER['KRB5CCNAME']` in my request and I need to delegate this to another server using curl.

How can this be done?

Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$url = 'http://www.somesite.com/info.php';

@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GSSAPI_DELEGATION, CURLGSSAPI_DELEGATION_FLAG);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ":");

@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$resultContent = @curl_exec($ch);

$httpCode = @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if(@curl_errno($ch))
{
    $msg = @curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    die('Curl error: content: '.$this->resultContent.' code: '.$this->httpCode);
}

curl_close($ch);

die('R: code: '.$httpCode.' content: '. htmlspecialchars($resultContent));
```

EDIT:

I just figured it out that php 5.3 hasn't got CURLOPT_GSSAPI_DELEGATION, it's been added in 5.5.0 alpha 3.
Working on an issue to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Maybe use a POST request?

Comment: Please do some reading about kerberos before posting such a comment. Kerberos delegation isn't about making a same received request to other server.

Comment: Did you compile `curl` with SPNEGO support?

Comment: No, but as I read it, it's not needed if you use CURLOPT_GSSAPI_DELEGATION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html
**CURLOPT_GSSAPI_DELEGATION**

> Set the parameter to CURLGSSAPI_DELEGATION_FLAG to allow unconditional
>   GSSAPI credential delegation. The delegation is disabled by default
>   since 7.21.7. Set the parameter to CURLGSSAPI_DELEGATION_POLICY_FLAG
>   to delegate only if the OK-AS-DELEGATE flag is set in the service
>   ticket in case this feature is supported by the GSSAPI implementation
>   and the definition of GSS_C_DELEG_POLICY_FLAG was available at
>   compile-time.

OK-AS-DELEGATE flag should be set in the Kerberos service ticket (realm policy).

Comment: Already tried, our curl version is 7.22 so I presume GSS_C_DELEG_POLICY_FLAG was available at compile time. I will post our code and more explanation, still it doesn't work.

Comment: Not all curl compiled editions are compiled against GSS API, so you might want to check that within phpinfo().

Comment: Already checked, it has GSS compiled, but it doesn't have CURLOPT_GSSAPI_DELEGATION as it's added in php 5.5.0, this is still alpha version, so we'll wait a bit longer